# Nodejs C++ event emitter. add-on error. Non-function in MakeCallback. method = emit Abort trap: 6

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm creating a C++ level event emitter addon for node.js. I'm getting this C++ error when including the add-on in a node.js project.

`Non-function in MakeCallback. method = emit Abort trap: 6`

I found this Gist with a simplified example of the same behavior: 
https://gist.github.com/jedi4ever/4250746

Hoping for some general insight into why this might be caused or what this error means.

Comment: Hard to guess your structure, but are you inheriting EventEmitter and calling back using something like `MakeCallback(args.This(), "emit", 2, params);` (args being the `const Arguments&` passed into your method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you have a couple of problems in your keylogger.js file;

```js
util.inherits(new keylogger, events.EventEmitter);
exports = keylogger;
```

You're trying to extend an instance, and your export statement is a bit off. This should work better to export keylogger as an instance which the test file seems to expect;

```
util.inherits(keylogger, events.EventEmitter);
exports.keylogger = new keylogger();
```

Comment: looks like this error is indeed thrown from improper eventEmitter inheritance.